# Linear Interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

Just want to ask if this scenario is still  possible in linear interpolation. If not, what interpolation would I need to get the missing value:

X1 = 50
Y1 = 35
Z1 = 60

X2 = 70
Y2 = 40
Z3 = 70

X3 = 55
Y3 = 30
Z3 = ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use linear interpolation, as follows: Using the ansatz
\[ z = ax + by \]
We get the linear system
\begin{align*}
  50a + 35b &= 60\\
  70a + 40b &= 70
\end{align*}
which has the solution $a = \frac 19$, $b = \frac{14}9$. So 
\[ Z_3 \approx\frac 19 \cdot \left( 1 \cdot 55 + 14 \cdot 30\right) = 52\frac 79. \]